# How could I translate this MySql Query to MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to run a query like this in MongoDB:

```
SELECT kills / deaths AS kd FROM stats
```

My documents look like this:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5b6e8c66568a4e65461a5893"),
"uuid": "889fd936-1a1e-31ac-b1fc-1ca34576301d",
"coins": 146,
"onlinetime": 988,
"logins": 540,
"messages": 31,
"rounds": 0,
"lobby": {
    "balloons": {
        "skeleton": true,
        "creeper": true,
        "enderdragon": true,
        "wither": true
    },
    "jumpandrun": true
},
"stickfight": {
    "inventory": {
        "stick": 0,
        "blocks": 1
    },
    "rounds": 26,
    "kills": 219,
    "deaths": 156
}
```

Some of the documents don't have `stickfight` inside. I want to divide `kills` with `deaths` and check if the rounds are higher than 15.

I need the 5 best players.

https://pastebin.com/AqscMYSp

I tried this:

```
$agg = $coll->aggregate([
        ['$project' => [
            'id' => '$_id'
        ]],
        ['$unwind' => '$stickfight'],
        ['$group' => [
            "_id" => '$id',
            "kills" => '$stickfight.kills',
            'deaths' => '$stickfight.deaths'
        ]]
    ])->toArray();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: i did it now c:

Comment: Nopes we need expected output and that doesn't seems to be

Comment: Could you share the code you tried to make it happen?

Comment: added my code now